# iOS - add horizontal padding to tableview cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

I want to add horizontal padding for my table view cells as the image shows.

I created a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, whose width was 314 pixels (screen's width is 320), and set its frame in the `initWithCoder` method:

```
[self customizeXPosition:self.profileImage];
[self customizeXPosition:self.birthdayLabel];
[self customizeXPosition:self.heightLabel];
[self customizeXPosition:self.weightLabel];
```

this is my `- (void)customizeXPosition:(UIView *)view`:

```
- (void)customizeXPosition:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect tmpRect = view.frame;
    tmpRect.origin.x += 3.0;
    view.frame = tmpRect;
}
```

The custom cell was smaller than screen, and I moved every element in the cell to right by 3 pixels. I thought this code should achieve my goal, yet it didn't. The view didn't change in the simulator, just like I didn't write any code.

how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399402/grouped-uitableview-and-horizontal-margins

Comment: awesome! this link solved my problem! would you like to organize the info and answer this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try overriding the -setFrame method in UITableViewCell as per this post :

[How to set the width of a cell in a UITableView in grouped style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style)

[Swift version](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2fr849/uitableviewcell_with_custom_width_in_swift/)

Comment: btw @Brian, I think it'll be better to just make this the answer but go over to that SO page and up the user's answer. I won't want to take   credit for the perfect answer he gave. He helped me too! :) and for others who saw this answer please if that answer helped you, up vote his answer and not me. :)

Answer (score 3):

@faterpig is correct in many situations. However, setting frame may break auto layout.

If your auto layout is broken due to setting frame, you can add a `UIView` ,which has shorter width than the cell `contentView`, to the `contentView` and put your other UI elements on the view.

By doing the following settings, you can get cells with "horizontal padding":

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 2):

This works well for padding things in views:

yourView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0);

Comment: ouch, that's ugly! :D