# Make the cells fill the width of the section of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a UITableView that is grouped with many sections.  Each section has 1 to n cells.  I am trying to have the cells take the entire width, but cannot figure out how to do it.  I have searched but cannot find any samples or information of how to so it.

I have put an example screenshot below.

I have this:

[image]

And I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

I will be making the cell a square box with a gradient and styling the headers, but I cannot figure out how to make the cell fill the width of the screen.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the width of a cell, you could simply change the width of the table, or change the width of the contentView in the cell.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style) question details how to do the latter.

Comment: I did subclass the cell and I did override setFrame, I was able to  set the width, but the x location was still inset.

Comment: Yes, that does work if I specify a negative number for the x axis. I guess I was on the right track but overlooked negative numbers!!  Working now... thanks for the help!!