# set width of cell in grouped uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying this code to set width of cell when table is load. but it is properly work in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but not work in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** help me.

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(50, cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 44)
```

so when we click on cell it will change the width not directly when it is load..
yes i have tried also
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 30, cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 44)];
    }

see my all code of table methods

```
#pragma mark - Table Method

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 7;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ((section == 0) ?
            3 : (section == 1) ?
            1 : (section == 2) ?
            1 : (section == 3) ?
            2 : (section == 4) ?
            1 : (section == 5) ?
            1 : (section == 6) ?
            1 : 1);
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 30, cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 44)];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

       cell.frame = CGRectMake(50, cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 44);
        return cell;

    }
   if (indexPath.section >= 1)
    {

        cell.frame = CGRectMake( 30, cell.frame.origin.y, 200, 44);

    cell.textLabel.text=@"Dhaval";
    }

        return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.frame = CGRectMake(50, cell.frame.origin.y, 275, 44);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting width when cell is created i.e. inside `if(cell == nil) { }` in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style

Comment: yes anum90 i have also tried this.but it not works

Comment: jitendra this link will change the frame size of all my table view i want to change width of only cell.... like in add new contacts of inbuilt contact book of iphone