# Override method of Object Instance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, overriding, uitableview

I am trying to override the `setFrame` method of `UITableViewCell` inside of a class that inherits from `UITableViewController`. I found this method override as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style) but I don't know how to implement the override to get it to work.

Here is the override I want to implement:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    int inset = 1;
    frame.origin.x += inset;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

This is the class I want to use the override in:

```
@interface PeopleTableViewController : UITableViewController 
{
}

@end
```

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style) says to subclass `UITableViewCell` to override the method. How and where do I do this? Thanks in advance

EDIT: This is where the `UITableViewCell` is used.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    //USE TO SET CELL IMAAGE BACKGROUND

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"basketball.png"] 
                            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 
                                                topCapHeight:5.0]];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"basketball.png"] 
                                    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 
                                                        topCapHeight:5.0]];

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to override it in the view controller?

Comment: You override a method of a class by writing a subclass of THAT class, not some other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue here is that you are looking at your `UITableViewController` subclass. If you subclass `UITableViewCell` you will get some default method implementations. Just add your `setFrame` override in the implementation somewhere, like this:

```
#import "MyTableViewCellSubclass.h"

@implementation MyTableViewCellSubclass

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self; 
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state 
}

// YOUR ADDED setFrame OVERRIDE
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    int inset = 1;
    frame.origin.x += inset;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

Just to give you something to think about. `UIViewController`s do not have frames. They just control views (hence "viewController"). Views have frames. Hope that helps you understand why we put the `setFrame` override in a view class and not a controller class.

Comment: So if I make a subclass of UITableViewCell called MyTableViewCell and replace UITableViewCell *cell with MyTableViewCell, will all of the other automatically inserted code that was already there work? I will post the method I am talking about

Comment: It should, yes. If you do not override a method in a subclass it will just use the super class's by default. So in this case if you do not override anything else, it will act just like a `UITableViewCell` (with the exception of setting the frame because you overrode it)

Comment: Thank You! Worked just as you said. Sorry if that was a rookie question, thought it would be difficult since the first thing I looked up mentioned multiple inheritance. Appreciate the fast response :]

Comment: No problem. We were "rookies" at one point and in some area everyone still is. Just glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in a `UITableViewCell` subclass, this is the easiest and safest option.

If you want to do it in the view controller for some reason (you risk breaking a number of things) you would need to use method swizzling (because you want to call `super` so using a category won't work).