# Custom UITableViewCell width in iOS7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have been using customized `UITableViewController` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped` and custom group header, group footer and cell background. With iOS 7 the cell width has changed to full width of the `UITableView`. Is it possible to modify the group/cell width and still use `UITableViewController`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue. My (grouped style)tableView used to have it's cells inset about 10 px on the left and right side. With iOS7 the content in grouped table views is stretched to the edges of the tableview.

My fix was to adjust the width of the table view which would in turn adjust the width of the cells that it displays.

Comment: This approach will have an undesired impact if you have any header/footer views on the tableView

Answer (score 1):

This answer has a good solution for adjusting UITableViewCell custom width.  Use this in conjunction with a check for if the device is using iOS7, and you'll have a good solution.

[How to set the width of a cell in a UITableView in grouped style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style)