# how do you increase the padding for a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I increase the size of a `UITableViewCell`, the section headers styling becomes messy. The code I am using, was suggested in "[How to set the width of a cell in a UITableView in grouped style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style)" and is as follows:

I have inherited from `UITableViewCell` and created this class:

```
@implementation UITableViewCellHistory {
}

-(bool) isIPAD
{
    return UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ([self isIPAD])
    {
        NSInteger inset = 40;
        frame.origin.y += inset;
        frame.size.height -= 2 * inset;
        [super setFrame:frame];
    }
}
@end
```

then in my class with the table view in it I have used the above class as my cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == [data numberOfDaysWithData])
    {
        NSAssert([data hasMore], @"how come we have more sections than days when more is low?");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCellHistory alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

But when I increase the size of the padding further I the headings in the tableview get overlapped by rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style