# TableView ContentInset does not shrink cell width / Add horizontal padding to TableView contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, padding

I'd like to have a `UITableView` which is full screen. But the content of the `UITableView` should have a padding on the left and right.

So I tried to set `ContentInset`. But now the cells are as wide as the `UITableView` and the `UITableView` scrolls horizontally.

Is there a way to say that the `UITableView` content's width should become narrowed by the horizontal content insets? Or do I have to add the padding to all cells and header/footer views?

I don't want to narrow the table view itself, because the scroll indicator should stay at the right side of the screen and not in the middle.
The here ([How to set the width of a cell in a UITableView in grouped style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style)) suggested solution seems to be not as generic as i'd love to, beacuse the cells and header and footer views have to know about the padding (at least 3 places to maintain instead of one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want to narrow the table view itself, because the scroll
>   indicator should stay at the right side of the screen and not in the
>   middle.

This makes you happy?

```
_tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;
_tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -30.f);
```

If you don't like `clipsToBounds = NO` effects, you can embed the tableView in container view which is `clipsToBounds = YES`.

Comment: Thanks, I tested `scrollIndicatorInsets`, too, but forgot `clipsToBounds`. Now it looks like requested, but the scrolling behaviour sucks :D But thats not my problem (yet).

Comment: This is a fine solution UI-wise, but you cannot scroll using the indicator with it outside the table view's bounds

Answer (score 4):

Set the layout margins of the table view. For this to work make sure your constraints in the cells are set relative to the superview margin.

```
tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 40)
```

[image]