# iOS - How to reduce the width of a Table View Section (that contains TableViewCell)

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm developing an application using swift that contains a Table View with 3 static cell like this pic:

[image]

How can I reduce the width of the cells so that they do not touch the edge? I want to reduce a bit length

Comment: Decrease the width of the table view

Comment: sorry...how????

Comment: Same as Dan, decrease the width of the tableview, or if it's not possible, create a new custom cell, with clear color background, and add a new UIView to the cell, as a new content view.

Comment: @PéterKovács how decrease? I don't see any option!

Comment: Just like you increase and decrease width of label ,button, views . Do for table view.

Comment: Do you want to reduce width of tableview for specific section only?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR i have 1 section, yes, i want to reduce width of this only section. just like facebook login for smarphone :)

Comment: @user2324946 here is your answer -: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228496/change-width-of-tableviewcell-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your tableview and open the Size Inspector by pressing Command + Option/Alt + 5

Then you'll see few options here like this.

[image: size Inspector image]

Now change x and width options to reduce the width of tableview.