# file structure in table view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

can i show table view in this way

[image]

specification
000001,s able to hide all.

000003 is able to hide from 3 to 14..

000011 able to hide only 12,13 and 14..

Thanks,

Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `indentationlevelforrowatindexpath` method of `UITableViewDelegate`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502822/indentationlevelforrowatindexpath-not-indenting-custom-cell) -- it gives you the option of indenting different table cells with different amounts.

**However,** you need to ask yourself if the UI you propose is appropriate. Apple in their Human Interface Guidelines say that you should avoid presenting a tree-like control with too many levels in it, because it doesn't present well on a limited display space. In this case there's often a better mobile UI design available, e.g. break things up into different levels in a UINavigationController structure.

On the iPad obviously you have more screen real estate to play with, but it's still a point worth taking seriously.