# Add left indent to UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Please refer to this picture below:

[image: Result]

I want to customize a UITableView.

I achieved applying image background for it using tableView.backgroundView.

Now I want to add left indent/margin to every row as the example picture. Then I want to reduce their width and centerize them.

Could I achieve these? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I'd say that the better way is to customize the UITableViewCell... There are a lot of tutorial around the web.

Comment: Why don't you just set the frame of your UITableView ?
And yeah, if you want to indent, just customize trough UITableViewCell.

Comment: are you added the tableView to ypur project or choose the navigation template ?

Comment: @Snaker I want cells to stay inside a specific position inside my background image. If I set UITableView, would it affect my backgroundView as well?

Comment: @MidhunMP I added UITableView from Object Library, then add items programmatically. My ViewController is implemented UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: @Larme I stuck hours on Google to find a way to do this :(

Comment: If you set the background to the UITableView, yeah, by modifying the UITableView frame, you will also modify the background.

Comment: @Snaker so the setFrame solution won't work for me :)

Comment: Then you might take jimpic's answer : Setting the cells as tranparent.
Concerning the indentation, have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502822/indentationlevelforrowatindexpath-not-indenting-custom-cell) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a transparent view for your cells and center your content inside that cell. Or you can use

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for the indentation part.

Comment: @jimpic doesn't work, but I don't see a reason why. Could you update your answer with more details? Thanks.

Comment: This may not work for you if you are using a custom UITableViewCell.