# indentation is not working in UITableView ( ios6)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

The cell is not indenting according to is level.

I have configured indentation width inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            NSInteger theLevel=0;
            if ( indexPath.row==1) {
                theLevel=5;
            }
            return theLevel;
        }
```

In the below image I changed frame frame of button and label according to its level.

[image]

Comment: Your question says there's an image but you haven't added it. Please add.

Comment: Are you using custom cells?

Comment: @MikeD no I am not using any custom cell.Just adding subviews to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added subviews to the cell then you need to set the subviews' autoresizing masks so that they are repositioned when the contentView size gets changed.

Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502822/indentationlevelforrowatindexpath-not-indenting-custom-cell).

Comment: Even I have removed subviews and then tried to indent still its not working

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        
   // Add button(expand/collapse) and label on cells.
   [self addSubviewsToCell :cell];
  }return cell;
}

Comment: Please Edit your question and post code there. [self addSubviewsToCell :cell] is commented ?