# UITableViewCell indentation works only for default cell textLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indentation

I have got custom `UITableViewCell` and not able set indentation in `cellForRow: atIndexPath:`.

```
cell.indentationWidth = 10.0
cell.indentationLevel = indexTuples.count //Dynamic
```

However, this works if iOS provided default cell label :

`cell.textLabel?.text = "TEST"`

Is there any restriction? How can I solve this ?

Note: I have to use `Autolayout`.

**UPDATE**:

As per comments, I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502822/indentationlevelforrowatindexpath-not-indenting-custom-cell), I gave a try with below code which doesn't seems to be helpful.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.layoutMargins.left = CGFloat(self.indentationLevel) * self.indentationWidth
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath not indenting custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502822/indentationlevelforrowatindexpath-not-indenting-custom-cell)

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari Thanks for sharing link.  However overriding layoutSubviews of cell doesn't helped me. But a simple autolayout trick solved my problem. ;-)

Comment: Am glad u solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *In short  :*  With the help of Autolayout leading constraint, I am able to solve this problem.

First I created a UIView say `containerView` inside cell contentView & moved all the elements of cell `contentView` into  `containerView`. Later I made  `IBOutlet` of "constainerView leading constraint".

Then in the `cellForRow: atIndexPath` table view delegate updated its constant as :

```
cell.indentViewLeading.constant = 5 + CGFloat(10 * indexTuples.count - 1)  //indexTuples.count gives dynamic values
cell.indentationWidth = 10.0
cell.indentationLevel = indexTuples.count
```

In my UITableViewCell subclass :

```
@IBOutlet weak var indentViewLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Comment: Why do you still need cell.indentationWidth =10.0 and cell.indentationLevel = indexTuples.count? Isn't adjusting your leading constraint enough? If apple enables indentation for your custom cell indentation is going to double.....